# Presto divide row pairs by common names

Tags: sql, presto

Say I have a presto statement returning

```
|Name|Type    |Count|
|A   | total  |   2 |
|A   | count  |   4 |
|B   | total  |   3 |
|B   | count  |   9 |
```

How do I achieve something like

```
|Name|Avg |
|A   |  2 |
|B   |  3 |
```

Basically

```
A.avg = A.count/A.total
B.avg = B.count/B.total
```

Thanks

PS: Not that versed in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way with a self join

```
select a.Name, 
Total/Count as Avg 
from (select Name, Count as total From tbl where Type = 'total')a
inner join (select Name, Count From tbl where Type = 'count') b on a.Name = b.Name
```

Comment: @Neo . . . this is much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use conditional aggration:

```
select name,
       ( max(case when type = 'count' then count end) /
         max(case when type = 'total' then count end)
       ) as average
from t
group by name;
```

Actually, if we assume that `total` >= `count`, then this is even simpler:

```
select name, min(count) / max(count) as average
from t
group by name;
```

If you really preferred `join` over `group by`:

```
select t.name, tc.count / tt.count
from t tc join
     t tt
     on tc.name = tt.name and
        tc.type = 'count' and
        tt.type = 'total';
```